# Utilizar nombre de tabla diferente a users para el login y registro

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera utilizar un nombre de tabla diferente a users que viene por defecto en laravel.

Como podria utilizar un nombre de tabla diferente para el login y registro que tendra algunas columnas mas.

Esa misma tabla hara el login y registro. Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás utilizando el modelo `User` para la autenticación, debes modificar la propiedad `$table` dentro de éste:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'usuarios';
}
```

También debes modificar la tabla en la que se realiza la validación de unique para el campo email en el registro, esto se hace en app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    // ...

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:usuarios',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
       ]);
    }
```

Comment: me funciona para el login, como seria para el registro? esta utilizando la tabla users para registrar

Comment: En teoría funciona igual, ¿qué mensaje de error te aparece?

Comment: valida si existe el email en la tabla users, me registra correctamente si no esta en la tabla users

Comment: Simplemente cambia la validación de unique para que lea la otra tabla en vez de usuarios.

Comment: en que archivo estaria esa validacion? @Shaz

Comment: En RegisterController: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L52

Comment: Con esa modificación funciona perfecto! gracias @Shaz